# Android studio crashes after i press button, with 0 errors

Tags: android

When i press login button app doesnt close but puts me in desktop mode on phone than i go again on the app and try to "login" and than it crashes

```
package com.example.coronaapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);

        Button login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        Button register = findViewById(R.id.register_btn);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // čia bus vykdomas kodas, kai paspaudžiamas mygtukas
                // Kuriamas User klases objektas
                //  public User(String username, String password)
                User user = new User(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "prisijungimo vardas:" +
                        user.getUsername() + "\n" + "slaptazodis:" +
                        user.getPassword(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                        username.getText().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                username.setError(null);
                if (Validation.isValidUsername(username.getText().toString())) {
                    Intent goToSearchActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(goToSearchActivity);
                    password.setError(null);
                }
                if (Validation.isValidUsername(password.getText().toString())) {
                    Intent goToSearchActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(goToSearchActivity);
                } else {
                    username.setError("Error Wrong username");
                    username.requestFocus();
                    password.setError("Wrong Password");
                    password.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent goToRegisterActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(goToRegisterActivity);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

im new to java, i tried many ways that i found on stackoverflow but it just doesnt work. Even if i delete half the code and try to go with only validation after click still crashes

Comment: look for the crash line in Android studio's logcat

Comment: Is this all you doing? I tried your code without validation check and it works fine. It would be nice if you could give more information like add your validation code or add the logcat message.